# How to use a specific webpack config file for running Jest?

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to write a test using Jest and import an es6 module. I am currently using webpack3 and jest 21.0.2. My test code starts with

```
import Const from 'Util/Const';
```

This throws an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import".
I have development.webpack.config.js and production.webpack.config.js files for development and production build. webpack.config.js files basically reads env variable and determines which file to refer.

Below code is a part of development.webpack.config.js to handle this error:

```
env: {
    test: {
        presets:['react',["es2015"]],
        plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "dynamic-import-node"]
    }
}
```

It seems like when I run npm test, Jest is not referring to development.webpack.config.js. Is there any way to set specific webpack config file when running Jest?

Comment: This works with .babelrc, but not with webpack config file.